# How do you disable the Trackpoint Mouse Pointer (nubby button mouse) on a Dell laptop?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, trackpoint

I'm really annoyed with my Dell laptop, as when I type the cursor sometimes jumps because the Trackpoint Mouse Pointer on the keyboard (the nubby mouse control between the <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, and <kbd>B</kbd>) apparently can be used to click. Is there a way to disable it from Windows?

Comment: Is it a physical click or is it just when it registers a touch? (Slightly off topic, I'm definitely printing that out for the office. Too much blushing going on when looking for the "bag of spare nipple tips").

Comment: It registers touch and then the cursor jumps. It's really annoying.

Comment: Ooh that's really bad design. No offence, I was kinda hoping you were just being too heavy handed. Surely, Dell being Dell, they shipped a bunch of bloat ware including the drivers for that darned thing?

Comment: If you came for the same question but for Linux, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424821/disable-laptop-pointing-stick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Dell touchpad driver software, there is an option to disable the TrackPoint and TouchPad.

You should be able to get to the touchpad software as follows:

Start > Settings > Control Panel > Mouse > Dell Touchpad > Device Select > Pointing Stick > Disable

Answer (score 5):

This largely depends on which model of Dell laptop you have. On certain models, as long as the Dell drivers are installed, there is a hotkey for the touchpad/point that will toggle the available settings.  On Latitude E7440, the hotkey is accessed by <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. Note that the <kbd>F5</kbd> key has a blue icon of the touchpad:

[image: Latitude E7440 keyboard]

This will toggle the TouchPoint Off, Trackpad Off, both Off, and both On, with an on-screen graphic indicating the setting.

On other models (for example the E7450), the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+ shortcut for this function is not present. Instead, you must use the Dell control panel to manage the nub and trackpad.

Comment: [The (Win)+X shortcut](http://tipsplanet.blogspot.com/2011/06/keyboard-shortcut-to-open-windows.html) opens the [Windows Mobility Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-mobility-center) (included on laptops running the Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate editions of Windows 7).  [Dell’s customization of that for the Inspiron 3542](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ym1nb.png) (which has a touchpad, and not a pointing stick) includes a panel for controlling/configuring the touchpad.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `C:\Program Files\DellTPad` and run `DellTPad.exe`

Select device
[image]

Disable touchpad
[image]

Comment: This is a good answer for a Dell Latitude E7450 whereby a Fn shortcut is not included.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually pull the rubbery top of the trackpoint pointing stick off quite easily, this might help avoid the problem. There's a small grey square joystick base underneath.

I found that when the E7450 screen is closed, the trackpoint leaves a faint black circular pressure / dust mark on the screen. I've take the top of the trackpoint off to prevent any possible damage and to stop this circle being left on the screen.

Comment: you are a life saver :), i cannot install the dell drivers because when i do there is some magnetic affect when another laptop is near my laptop! and this makes the mousepad unusable (i cannot even move the mouse, or it moves alone!), but this never happens with the default drivers provided by windows, so there is no option to disable the middle mouse button, but now i can thanks to your solution, thank again :)